# jQuery selectors select from an HTML object other than from document root?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

jQuery selectors select from the document.
How do I select from somewhere else other than root?
Say I want to select some children from an HTML object.

For this

```
function dothis(obj)
{
     $j("#tabs").removeClass();
     $j("#tabs>ul").removeClass();
     $j("#tabs>ul>li>a").each(function()
     {
         var tabNum = $j(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
         var tabContent = $j("div[id=" + tabNum + "]");
         tabContent.removeClass();
         $(tabContent).before("<br><h1>" +$j(this).text() + "</h1>\n" );
     });
     $j("#tabs>ul").each(function()
     {
         $j(this).empty();//remove Ul links on top

     });
}
```

I want to reference the selectors from an HTML Object (`obj`) i passed into as argument, instead of selecting from document.

This works!

```
$j("#tabs", obj).removeClass();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a second parameter to your selector to precise the context :

```
$j("#tabs", obj).removeClass();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$j(obj).find('#tabs')
```

to specify in which elements context you want so lookup something. Some people prefer this syntax:

```
$j('#tabs', obj)
```

which I would **not** recommend. It internally will convert it to the exact same as I mentioned above (`.find()`) and secondly, it is harder to read because of a switched order.

Answer (score 1):

If `obj` is an HTML Element, you can use the `context` parameter to [`jQuery(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

> ### `jQuery( selector, [ context ] )`
>
> `selector` A string containing a selector expression
> `context` A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

I.E. `$j("#tabs",obj).removeClass()`

You can also use the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) method on a **jQuery object** to look for children of the matched element, and internally `$(selector, context)` just calls `$(context).find(selector)` anyway.

For example:

```
function dothis(obj) {
  var $obj = $j(obj);
  $obj.find('#tabs').removeClass();
  // ....
}
```

Although, for either example, `#tabs` will be searching for an element with the ID `tabs`, there can only ever be one element with any given ID in the document, you may need to switch to using a class if you want to make this function work in two different contexts.