# Get partial HTML with AJAX

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a content of a another page using AJAX call. I am able to get the entire document but is it possible to get a better precision and get only a section that is within a target div?

```
<div class="myTarget">content that I need</div>
```

Here's how I get it now:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/dir/targetPage",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('#dropHere').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: This should point you in the right direction.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004340/jquery-selectors-select-from-an-html-object-other-than-from-document-root

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('#dropHere').load('/dir/targetPage #ele');
```

Where '#ele' is an element with the id of `ele` and all it's inner children.

Comment: @santa - just so you realize, this still fetches the entire document - then jQuery extracts one portion and throws the rest away.

Comment: @jfriend00 yep that's exactly what it does!

Comment: I'm fine with that! Still great!